# Asymptote: Ghostscript error with graph3

Tags: asymptote, ghostscript

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asydef}
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;
import graph3;
\end{asydef}

\begin{asy}[inline=true]
size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(4,6,3);

typedef triple myFunc(real);
myFunc foo(real y) {
  return new triple(real x) {return (x, y, sqrt(1-x*x-y*y));};
}

path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,0)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,0)..cycle;
draw(surface(g),gray(0.95));
for (real x = 0; x <= 0.3; x += 0.1) {
  real y = sqrt(1-x*x);
  draw((y,x,0)--(-y,x,0), gray(0.8));
  draw(graph(foo(x),-y,y));
}
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

This works fine and as expected.  But as soon as I change 0.3 to 0.4 in the for loop, it doesn't work anymore.  Ghostscript stops with some kind of unrecoverable error.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think it is a rounding error and `foo(.3)(-.3)` requires the square root of a negative number. Please add `abs` in the definition of `foo`.

Comment: @O.G. Yep, you're right, that was the problem.  Thanks!